# How to check if a record in a table also exists in another table or not in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables "order_manager" and "aamarpay". Both the table has a column named "transaction_id". It is a 10 character long randomly generated string.  I'm trying to verify if a payment is made successfully or not. If the payment is successful the transaction_id from "order_manager" table would also exist in the "aamarpay" table. Here are the structures of the tables:
[order_manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lk6rP.jpg)
[aamarpay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHP1M.jpg)

If the condition returns true then I would update "payment_status" from "order_manager" table to "successful".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test this:

```sql
UPDATE order_manager
SET payment_status = 'successful'
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
               FROM aamarpay
               WHERE aamarpay.transaction_id = order_manager.transaction_id )
-- AND payment_status <> 'successful'
```